# Android gallery app won't start after install due to NullPointerException in Intent

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a newbie in java and using Android Studio. My app won't launch after install. Checking the source code and XML, I can't seem to find any errors. Please help me check the code below

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<File> list;
    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.image_grid);

        list = imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        gridView.setAdapter(new gridAdapter());

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("img", list.get(i).toString());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

    public class gridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return list.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View convertView = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
                ImageView myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
                myImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(list.get(i).toString()));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<File> imageReader(File externalStorageDirectory) {

        ArrayList<File> b = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] files = externalStorageDirectory.listFiles();

        for (int i =0; i<files.length; i++){

            if (files[i].isDirectory()){

                b.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));

            }else {

                if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {

                    b.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

**This is the activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/image_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the FullImageActivity.java**

```
public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView fullImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

        fullImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.full_image);

        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img");

        fullImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data));
    }
}
```

**activity_full_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FullImageActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/wp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I will be glad if my question is attended to, as it is eating deep into me.

**This is the LOGCAT**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.jkjworks.galleryextra.FullImageActivity.onCreate(FullImageActivity.java:19)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7030
```

**#2 UPDATE MANIFEST AND BUILD.GRADLE**

**This is the MANIFEST**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
            <activity android:name=".FullImageActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is the APP level Build.gradle**

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.galleryextra"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: post your `logcat` errors.

Comment: i have updated the post with the requested LOGCAT.

Comment: What version of Android is this app running on? What is the Min SDK version you have the project set to? You can find this information in `Project Struture` tab `Flavors`. Also Include your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: I have updated the request with both Manifest and Build.gradle.        I tried your solution (update #2) but the App still failed on start. Please help me look at the manifest and app level buld.gradle above. I'm full of thanks for your wonderful efforts so far

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that `list.get(i)` is not `null`? I would put a breakpoint and analyze the return value of `list.get(i)` to ensure that what you are passing over is valid data.

Also, Use `intent.getStringExtra("img")` instead of `getIntent().getExtras().getString("img")`

Your problem is that `getIntent()` is receiving `NULL` and you are attempting to access it, thus causing a `NullPointerException` to take place.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.merizekworks.galleryextra.FullImageActivity.onCreate(FullImageActivity.java:19)
```

**Edit (Quick breakdown on how to debug)**
The best thing you can do is step thru your code via the debugger. If you've never done this, it's actually very easy to do and will help you see what the problem is.

In `MainActivity` change  this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("img", list.get(i).toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

To this, to help us debug a bit easier:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
    File selectedFile = list.get(i); //PUT BREAKPOINT ON THIS LINE
    String filePath = selectedFile.toString();
    intent.putExtra("img", filePath );
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

NOTE: If you are not familiar with debugging your code then I strongly recommend you spend a couple of minutes and read this article. In my opinion, it's the most valuable tool a programmer has. [Click here to learn how to debug in Android Studio](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/user-interface-basics-637d41b1-35dc-400a-bcc3-65794760474d/debugging-breakpoints-and-the-android-debugger)

[image: Breakpoint set (red circle on the left)]

The red circle on the left is the breakpoint, the code will stop execution here and you can analyze each variable, as seen in the screenshot above. You can even "Evaluate Expressions" while your app is running and execution was paused by a breakpoint. Doing so will let you grab any object current in memory and test against it.

For example, with the breakpoint we set above we can then use the "Evaluate Expression" button that's within the "Debugs" tab:

[image: How to set breakpoint and debug in AndroidStudio]

Here is a quick screenshot on how to Evaluate Expressions from an article on how to use the AndroidStudio debugger ([Full guide here](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%201/31_c_the_android_studio_debugger.html)):

[image: How to use Evaluate Expression in AndroidStudio]

---

**UPDATE #2**

Note, if you are using API 23 or higher, then you have to make sure you
have permission to READ/WRITE from the Android device.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `Manifest` tag include this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then here is the solution I use in my project which works very well for me, especially if you plan on request multiple permissions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = "DEBUG";
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<File> list;
    private GridView gridView;

    private final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 1;
    private String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        int totalGrantedCount = 0;
        for(int x=0; x < grantResults.length; x++){
            if (grantResults[x] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                totalGrantedCount++;
            }
        }

        if(totalGrantedCount == grantResults.length){
            startApp();
        }else{
            boolean somePermissionsForeverDenied = false;
            for(String permission: permissions){
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)){
                    //denied
                    Log.d(TAG, "PERMISSIONS: DENIED " + permission);
                }else{
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        //allowed
                        Log.d(TAG, "PERMISSIONS: ALLOWED " + permission);
                    } else{
                        //set to never ask again
                        somePermissionsForeverDenied = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(somePermissionsForeverDenied){
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Permissions Required")
                        .setMessage("You have forcefully denied some of the required permissions " +
                                "for this action. Please open settings, go to permissions and allow them manually.")
                        .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                        Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        })
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("PERMISSIONS DENIED")
                        .setMessage("Unable to proceed, this application requires that permissions be accepted to operate correctly. \r\n\r\n YOU MUST APPROVE ALL PERMISSIONS BEFORE CONTINUING.")
                        .setPositiveButton("TAP HERE TO CLOSE AND TRY AGAIN.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                                activity.finish();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.activity = this;

        //REQUIRED FOR API 23+ - REQUEST FOR PERMISSIONS - ONLY REQUIRED TO BE DONE ONCE PER APP INSTALL.
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    PERMISSIONS,
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }else{
            startApp();
        }

    }

    public void startApp(){
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.image_grid);
        list = imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        gridView.setAdapter(new gridAdapter());
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("img", list.get(i).toString());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class gridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return list.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View convertView = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
                ImageView myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
                myImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(list.get(i).toString()));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<File> imageReader(File externalStorageDirectory) {

        ArrayList<File> b = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] files = externalStorageDirectory.listFiles();

        for (int i =0; i<files.length; i++){

            if (files[i].isDirectory()){

                b.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));

            }else {

                if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {

                    b.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please I need better description of the solution above. Correct me from the MainActivity.java and FullImageActivity.java. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Merinze I updated my answer with a breakdown on how to do some debugging. Hope this helps you a bit, the goal is for you to find out what the list is returning to see what is being passed via the intent.

Comment: if i tell you i understand anything about the Debugger procedure eschewed above then i must be lying. Please tell me exactly what to do to get that java code working for now, while i find special time to learn more about App Debugger procedure. I spent couple of days but couldn't achieve anything. Please your help is what i need now. Thanks for your wonderful time.

Comment: I feel like boxed in one corner. No body to help me get out of it.